# Read int vector in R, 4 bytes per int

Tags: r, vector, binary-data

I have a 1 GB file, which is a vector of 250M elements, each being a 4-byte-`int` (saved with C++).

How to load this into a R vector? Would this be the natural way?

```
f = file("myfile.dat")
readBin(f, integer(), n = 250000000, size = 4, endian = "little")
```

Comment: Is each element on its own line?

Comment: No there is no item separator. Each element takes 4 bytes, so element `n` is at byte offset `4*n` of the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact the problem was just the open `binary` mode:

```
f = file("myfile.dat", open="rb")
readBin(f, integer(), n = 250000000, size = 4, endian = "little")
```

Comment: Was just about to comment to that effect :)